# doxygen namespace macro shows up in function section

Tags: namespaces, doxygen

I use doxygen in my C++ project. I have some header files with static const strings wich define network communication json structures. These strings are structured by using namespaces. To hide these namespaces I use [this](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Ignoring-a-Namespace-tp1941p1942.html) method. But if I close a namespace the namespace macro shows up in the functions section in the documentation.

Here is a example:

```
#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE(N) namespace N {
#define END_NAMESPACE() }

BEGIN_NAMESPACE(main_space)
static const std::string kVar1= "var1";

BEGIN_NAMESPACE(sub_space)
    static const std::string kVar2 = "var2";
END_NAMESPACE()

static const std::string kThisIs = "wrong documented";
static const std::string kNoProblem = "here";
END_NAMESPACE()
```

In documentation I get:

```
Functions:
END_NAMESPACE() static const std::string kThisIs
```

So `END_NAMESPACE()` is documented in functions section and `kThisIs` is missing in the `Variables` section.

The preprocessor configuration is as default expect I activated MACRO_EXPANSION. Is there a way to remove `END_NAMESPACE()` from function section and show `kThisIs`in variables section?

edit 1: added kNoProblem to show that kThisIs is not only variable. Additionaly I added that I activated MACRO_EXPANSION.

Comment: Did you have a look at MACRO_EXPANSION? Also note that when variables are not documented and EXTRACT_ALL is set you also look at the setting of EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC.

Comment: MACRO_EXPANSION, EXTRACT_ALL, EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC is all set (I use doxywizard).

Comment: an you create a small example including the Doxyfile (generated with doxygen -s to make it a bit smaller) and post this either as a bug report in bugzilla or better in the doxygen forum.